# Completion handler in a map function

Tags: swift, asynchronous

I am trying to create a chat app in iOS. Specifically, I want to take my list of chat participant IDs, go to Firestore and pull their full names, and return a list of all chat participant names.

Since Firestore takes a while to return, I put the `getUserName` function in a completion handler. My code looks like this:

```
func getParticipantNames(members: [String], patientID: String) -> [String] {
  let messageParticipantIDs = (members.filter{$0 != patientID})
  var messageParticipantNames: [String] = []
  messageParticipantIDs.map { UserData(id: $0).getUserName { (name) -> Void  in
    messageParticipantNames.append(name)
    print("name: \(name)")
  } 
  }

  return messageParticipantNames
}

// In UserData file
func getUserName(completionHandler: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
  let docRef = ...
    
  docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
    if let document = document {
      let firstName = document.data()!["firstName"] as! String
      let lastName = document.data()!["lastName"] as! String
                            
      completionHandler(firstName + " " + lastName)
    }
  }
}
```

However, the messageParticipantNames array keeps returning empty even though `print("name: \(name)")` is printing out the name correctly. I decided to append names to the messageParticipantNames array since Swift doesn't allow me to return anything from `{ UserData(id: $0).getUserName { (name) -> Void  in ...`.

I also tried using DispatchGroups but it still keeps returning empty strings. My code looked like:

```
func getParticipantNames(members: [String], patientID: String) -> String {
  let messageParticipantIDs = (members.filter{$0 != patientID}) 
  let messageParticipantNames = messageParticipantIDs.map { UserData(id: $0).fullName }

  return messageParticipantNames.joined(separator:",")
}

//In UserData file
init(id: String) {
    self.id = id   
    getUserName()
}

func getUserName() {
  let docRef = ...
  let group = DispatchGroup()
    
  group.enter()
  docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
    if let document = document {
      self.firstName = document.data()!["firstName"] as! String
      self.lastName = document.data()!["lastName"] as! String
                            
      group.leave()
    }
  }
    
  group.notify(queue: .main) {
    self.fullName = self.firstName + " " + self.lastName
  }
}
```

EDIT: Also tried batching the all the `group.enter()` together but names still returns empty. Swift doesn't allow me to return anything from `group.notify()`.

```
func getParticipantNames(members: [String], patientID: String) -> [String] {
  let messageParticipantIDs = (members.filter{$0 != patientID})
  let group = DispatchGroup()

  for _ in 0..<messageParticipantIDs.count {
    group.enter()
    print("enter")
  }

  var names: [String] = []
  messageParticipantIDs.map { (participantID) -> Void in
    let docRef = ...
    var firstName = ""
    var lastName = ""
    
    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document {
            firstName = document.data()!["firstName"] as! String
            lastName = document.data()!["lastName"] as! String
                            
            group.leave()
            print("leave")
        }
    }
    
    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        print("firstName lastName")
        print(firstName + " " + lastName)
        names.append(firstName + " " + lastName)
    }
  }

  print("names: \(names)")
  return names
}
```

This prints out:

1. enter,
2. names: [],
3. leave,
4. firstName lastName,
5. Example Name

The problem is I can't return anything from the `group.notify(queue: .main)` function and anything outside of that gets returned right away.

Comment: Until you can use TaskGroups in Swift 5.5 when that becomes more prominent, you'll need to use DispatchGroups.

Comment: What are you going to do if Firestore returns an error?

Comment: "the messageParticipantNames array keeps returning empty"  When?

Comment: @Alexander I had tried using DispatchGroups but didn't work :( I updated my question to show what I tried

Comment: @mj23 Your groups... aren't groups. You're making a separate one per call. You need to group all your calls to enter the same group together, and leave one by one as they complete.

Comment: @Alexander Ahh so I should call group.enter() from getParticipantNames function instead? How do I pass the group to the getUserName function?

Comment: i have doubt in this line `let docRef = ... ` please share this line code and some db structure detail. it might be helpful to understood what's the problem.

Comment: @mj23 It doesn't matter where precisely the exact structure here is a little muddied. The important part is that you have only one shared group, not one group per request (which does nothing)

Comment: @Alexander I modified as you suggested. I still keep running into the problem that I can't return anything from group.notify(queue: .main) and anything outside of that gets returned right away.